# TTL gate function

Tags: digital-logic, bjt, logic-gates, ttl

Can you explain the logic function of this TTL gate? I think it is
$$
Y = \overline{AB+CD} \
$$
but I am not sure. 
If 
$$
V_1=5V \\
V_2=0V
$$
does the transistor Q1 work in reverse-active mode?

[image: TTL gate]

Comment: Why not use your favorite simulator and see for yourself?

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh the AND_OR_expander logic...........these used to be available, with external pins (two) across Q3 for arbitrary expansion

Comment: @Tyler, that's a dreadful suggestion - skive off to the simulator when you can simulate it in your head in 2 mins! Where's the fun in switching your mind off. (Anyway, give me half hour, I'll have an answer...might be longer :-) )

Comment: @analogsystemsrf you're one of the very small number of engineers who remembers them. There were other, similar, ICs that TI apparently made for a single customer then tried to sell to more customers. I was annoyed that they took up space in the TTL data book I had to thumb past to find what I was looking for.

Comment: Q1,Q2,Q7,Q8 are the kind of inputs all the 54/74 ICs had, including 54L/74L, 54H/74H, 54S/74S. 54LS/74LS had diode inputs to get AND function, rather than transistors.

Answer (score 1):

> does the transistor Q1 work in reverse-active mode?

Yes, but the current gain is very low so it will not be able to override a logic Low on the other input (when Q2 is pulling down).